# Beginner programming for a class, keep getting 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'

Tags: html, geojson

I'm really new to HTML and Javascript and I have a final project due soon and I am trying to call some data from OSM and I keep getting this error 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'

Here is the link to the map so far: http://gus8068sum16.github.io/FinalGroupProject.html

And this is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>

  <style>
    body {background-color: #C70039;}

    h1 {text-align: center;}
    h1 {color:  #FFFFFF;}
    h1 {font-family: Georgia
          font-style:normal;
          font-weight: bold;}

    h2 {text-align: center;}
    h2 {color:  #FFFFFF;}  
    h2 {font-family: Georgia
          font-style: italic;
          font-weight: normalc;}

    div {border-style: outset;
          border-color: #000000;
          border-width: 3px;
    }

  </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <h1> Temple University Main Campus Map </h1>
    <h2>Use this map to find your way around Temple University Main Campus in Philadelphia </h2>
    <div id="tumap" style="height:900px; width:1300px; margin:auto"></div>

     <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
     <script>

      var tumap = L.map('tumap').setView([39.981450,-75.154386], 17);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Contributors Elijah Diaz-Cruz, Jodie Spross, Laura Trzaska & Taryn Weisberg',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'jspross93.0d4ecll6',
   accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoianNwcm9zczkzIiwiYSI6ImNpcGVtcXo3cTAwMDFzdG5jc2lxdnN1NmEifQ.8-EK8kM2Apv_vSawAqfw0g'
}).addTo(tumap);

//function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
//    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
//        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
        //for when we are ready with the feature
//    }
//};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "http://overpass-api.de/api/xapi?map?bbox=-75.16196,39.97636,-75.14511,39.98475", false);
xhr.send();

var myJsonDictionary = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

L.geoJson(myJsonDictionary, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(tumap);

    </script>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: EDIT: my goal is to pull the node data from OSM and get some features to outline all the buildings and roads on campus, which I can then add popups and such to using 'oneachfeature'

Comment: You need to understand the basics of AJAX to do this, and if you are "due soon" oh boy am I sorry for you. But the main issue you have atm is, your request to the server does not return a JSON data file, so a file that begins with <xml is definitively a syntax error.

Comment: Our professor has never even mentioned AJAX, so we are expected to do this project without it. We were sort of 'tossed into the fire' so to speak in this class with no previous coding knowledge at all. Do you have any examples that would make the code work?

Comment: This is a very difficult task for someone without coding knowledge, overall, generally speaking, not because of AJAX, but everything alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your service is returning XML, and not Json at all. you should parse the XML response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.

Some services allow you to ask for JSON to be returned, by using xhr.setResponseType = 'json', but this service (overpass-api.de) ignores that and still returns xml.

See blog post here for example, or google for parsing xml in javascript.
https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json